# How to smoothly bend a shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been trying to bend a shape this way, but I find it hard, I don't know which tool should I use and even if I should start with a shape.

How is it possible to achieve these sort of smoothly curved lines?

[image: Example]

Comment: You would probably not bend anything

Comment: .. following up on that.. circles are drawn, as seen in the underlying paths... then split and connected... nothing is "bent" really.

Comment: How is it possible to connect the circles?